# Tomcat PoolExhaustedException - How to count connections?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

We had a recent issue with our Application which is running on Tomcat. The exception was related to exhausting the jdbc pools (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException)

We are planning to fix the code, but ..

1. How to enable trace so as to count the number of connection pools to
   DB?
2. Any options with Tomcat manager to view the connection pools?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way to count number of db2 connections per DB per IP address

```
db2 list applications for database <databaseName>| grep db2jcc_applica | grep -c <ip_address>
```

This will show all connections to the particular  coming from an ip_address. If the DB server is within your local Server, the ip_address would be "127.0.0.1"